# How to set left,right,top and bottom margins in mm scale in latex?

Tags: pdftex

I want to set the following page settings in Latex:

**Paper Size :** Standard A4 size (297mm x 210mm)

***Margins:***

**Top edge:** 35 mm

**Bottom edge :**  30 mm

**Left side :** 40 mm

**Right side :** 25 mm

**line spacing :** 1.5

**Font Style:** Times New Roman

**Font Size:** 13

I used the following code.

```
\documentclass[13pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={297mm,210mm},
 left=35mm,
 right=20mm,
 top=30mm,
 bottom=25mm,
}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\linespread{1.5}
%================================
\begin{document}
Sample Text ! Sample Text ! Sample Text ! Sample Text ! Sample Text ! Sample Text ! Sample Text ! 
%===============================
\end{document}
```

But it gives me error. Please guide me to set the above page settings in latex. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That seems to be xelatex or lualatex font syntax, did you use either one of those? Else drop those two lines as jorgepz suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can with `xelatex` and `fontspec`. In the following code, I calculated approximately the value for `\linespread`, based on the code from `setspace`: I computed the corresponding value for \baselineskip (15.6pt) and multiplied by 1.25.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, english]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\linespread{1.95}
 \geometry{
 left=40mm,
 right=25mm,
 top=35mm,
 bottom=30mm,
 showframe
}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Scale=1.3]{Times New Roman}
%================================
\begin{document}
Sample Text ! Sample Text ! Sample Text ! Sample Text ! Sample Text ! Sample Text ! Sample Text !

\lipsum
%===============================
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Bernard for your valuable response.. As per your suggestion, I used xelatex, but it shows as: The font Times New Roman can not be found.. Guide me for this scenario.. Thanks..

Comment: Also guide me for the font size 13 issue..

Comment: You have a font size equal to 13pt with the code `Scale=1.3`, since the default font size is 10pt. Is there any problem?

Comment: Thanks @Bernard..I am using Kile editor.. in that your code gives me the error:**fontspec package requires either xetex or luatex**.. I used xeLatex and luaLatex also .. But I got the same error.. Guide me for this scenario.. Thanks..

Comment: Did you have an error compiling with `xelatex`, with this very code?

Comment: Yes.. the error is: "fontspec package requires either xetex or luatex" in my system..

Comment: Is your installation up-to-date? And are you sure you compile with `xelatex`?

Comment: My Kile version is : 4:2.9.91-4 and I compiled with xelatex..

Comment: Kile is just  an editor. Which distribution do you have?

Comment: Latex2e.. If it is wrong, please guide me to check the latex distribution in ubuntu 18.04 .. I am very beginner to latex environment.. thanks..

Comment: Latex2e has been the official version for 25 years, and it is not a ‘distribution’… What I meant was, do you have TeX Live or MiKTeX. Perhaps you should update.

Comment: As per the link https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-latex-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux ,                                                                               " texlive-base - 136 MB
texlive-latex-recommended - 177 MB
texlive - 240 MB
texlive-latex-extra - 404 MB 
texlive-full - 4714 MB "                                                                                                             which version am I want to install?

Comment: The simplest is installing the full version, if you have enough space for that. Other than that, TeX Live Package Manager (tlmgr) enables you to install any package you please.

Comment: I don't have the space to install TexLive Full. My Tex version is : TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2017/Debian). For my problem what package am I want to install.

Comment: CHECK IF XELATEX IS TEALLY INSTALLER.

Comment: after installing XeTex and ttf-mscorefonts-installer it is working.. Thank you very much..

Answer (score 0):

The error should be caused by the 13pt option on article class (maximum is 12pt) and the fontspec package. If you really want to use LaTeX (pdflatex) then you could replace the lines:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
```

by this

```
\usepackage{times}
```

Comment: As mentioned by daleif , the error was: The fontspec package requires either xetex or luatex.. But after replacing those 2 lines with \usepackage{times} as suggested by jorgepz, I got output.. Thank you very much for your valuable response..

Comment: How can I use 13pt in latex?

Comment: I am glad that my answer was helpful. At https://texblog.org/2012/08/29/changing-the-font-size-in-latex/ you can find example commands to change sizes, at the bottom you have the "anyfontsize" package how to use.

Comment: thank you very much  @jorgepz for your link. In that article, the \usepackage{anyfontsize}  not supports the 13 font size as well as  in that article I found \documentclass[13pt]{extarticle}. That one also not supports the 13 font size.. I don't why.. Anyhow thank you for your valuable response..